# don`t work css and js files in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing a project  here  I have created layout page and i have located root css files however  I can`t see "Css" design at my dashboard page I shared layout.cshtml with you  Even I located app.StaticFiles  just still don work in your opinion what`s the problem
I need to finish this project as soon as possible, please help

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7693313d56.js"></script>
    
        <link href="~/css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/lightpick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/merchatdashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/mydatetime.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/css/swipe.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="leftmenuswipe">
            <div class="leftsidemenuswipe">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Menus)
                {
                    <div class="menuitemswipe document">
                        <div class="icon ">
                            <img src="@item.MENU_ICON">
                        </div>
                        <div class="link ">
                            <a href="# ">@item.MENUNAME_1</a>
                        </div>
                        @foreach (var sub in ViewBag.SubMenus)
                        {
                            if (item.ID == sub.MENU_PARENT_ID)
                            {
                                <ul class="document">
    
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">
                                            @sub.MENUNAME_1
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
    
                                </ul>
                            }
                        }
                        <div class="clear "></div>
                    </div>
    
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>
    
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7693313d56.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bar.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/bar_chart.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/countdown.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/dashboard.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/dashboardjquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/demo.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/lightpick.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/Loginajax.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/piechart.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/pie_chart.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/ReportAjax.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/reportform.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/swipe.js"></script>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

I dragged the css and javascript files I placed in the layout, it is true in the addresses, I tried every way, it is not solved again

[image]
[image]
[image]

you can look at this pictures which my Project

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Startup.cs file and see Configure method if it is using staticfiles
If not add

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```